# Are there any ide's out there with good support for vim/vi bindings?

Tags: vim, ide

Finding vim plugin maintenance and configuring is too laborious and relies on external configurations (such as ruby) tricky. What I want is an IDE like Eclipse, Visual Studio, that I can use vim in.  I still want to be able to use different modes (command, visual, insert), but I don't want these inbuilt commands to conflict with the IDE's commands.

I've heard [PIDA](http://pida.co.uk/) is good for this but looks like a bit of a mission to configure on Mac.

Answer (score 3):

Eclipse has a VIM plugin. Eclipse runs on OS X

http://www.vimplugin.org/

Also, I think the Komodo IDEs and editors have VIM bindings, but I have little experience with them. Apparently, they also run on OS X.

http://docs.activestate.com/komodo/4.4/vikeybind.html

Answer (score 3):

I use [Komodo Edit](https://www.activestate.com/products/komodo-edit/) on OS X, Ubuntu and Windows. It's open source, supports a ton of languages and has good Vi/Vim key binding support without getting in the way of itself. It's also easy to add in support for additional key bindings. It's built on the Mozilla code base and can be extended with Add-ons (Remote Drive Tree/Source Tree/MoreKomodo are great examples). I also personally love being able to write macros for myself in either JS or Python to add extra functionality.

The full fledged IDE is worth looking at if you can use the extra features. For most of the things that I work on, I can't use a full fledged remote debugger so Komodo Edit suits my needs.

It also has built in SSH support all in a package that is very responsive on my 5 year old work machine with several 1000 line files open in tabs.

Answer (score 2):

Emacs has a **vi** emulation mode [called Viper](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/viper/index.html#Top) ;-)

Comment: He's looking for an IDE, not an OS! :P

Answer (score 1):

Besides the vim plugin for Eclipse there is also [ViEmu](http://www.viemu.com/) for (amongst others) Visual Studio, if you are not afraid of shelling out some $. Haven't used it though, as vim is my IDE :)

Comment: There's now a free extension called VsVim available on NuGet.

Answer (score 1):

[This AutoHotKey script](http://blog.jpboodhoo.com/ByeByeArrowKeys.aspx) isn't quite what you asked for, but I mention it in case it's helpful.

Answer (score 1):

As you say, [PIDA](http://pida.co.uk) has real Vim, nothing can come close to that. Keybinding emulation only goes so far. It's not that bad to get running on a Mac, Windows is a mission though.

Answer (score 0):

[QT creator](http://qt.nokia.com/products/appdev/developer-tools/developer-tools) has Vi bindings.